# What would cause so many unstarted threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading, windbg

Now I have met a bug very strangely.

My application is a winform client that need connected to a server with WCF. My application would reference several .net and c++ modules/dlls.

For some reason, I have set `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(150, 200)` in my code. After running several hours, this client would disconnected with the server.

After debugged with windbg, I found the thread pool had been filled with many strange threads. So no new thread could be created in thread pool, and I think WCF also can't create the thread to connect with the server that cause disconnection.

These strange threads look like this:

```
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
XXXX   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

According to  [Yun Jin's WebLog "Thread, System.Threading.Thread, and !Threads" series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2005/08/25/456355.aspx) and [SSCLI 2.0 source code](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917), the highest probability of generating these threads is that CLR create a new thread in thread pool and the thread would never be resumed.

I want to know **why or how a thread or a lot of thread would be resumed failed**.

**The following are more technical details:**

When CLR create a new thread in thread pool, it will call `SetupUnstartedThread` method and `CreateNewThread/CreateNewOSThread` method.

After `SetupUnstartedThread`, CLR will create a thread like this

```
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
XXXX   3    0 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

Which has `0x1400 (TS_Unstarted | TS_WeOwn)` state and hasn't OSID and hasn't debugger ID (XXXX)

After `CreateNewThread/CreateNewOSThread`, the thread will become

```
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
XXXX   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

Which has OSID and also hasn't debugger ID (XXXX)

And further more, the thread's `ExposedObject` field is null.

But if the thread was resumed successfully, that means [`ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk`](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=205) was called, the thread would get the debugger ID (2)

```
                                                                         Lock  
   ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
2   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

The thread's status has been different from the wrong status (which hasn't debugger ID)

**Edit to  Thomas W**

if the option c you mentioned is

> (c) a special OS thread in CLR which might run managed code.

According [SSCLI 2.0 source code](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917), if the OS thread want to visit the managed code, CLR will invoke `SetupThread` method which would run the following codes

```
// reset any unstarted bits on the thread object
FastInterlockAnd((ULONG *) &pThread->m_State, ~Thread::TS_Unstarted);
FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pThread->m_State, Thread::TS_LegalToJoin);
```

Which definitely is not `0x1400`

Any strange thread has not the corresponding one in `~` thread list. So you can't see them in `!runaway`

**Edit 2**

Sorry for updating this post so lately. The root cause hasn't been found, but a workaround has been found, that is replacing **.Net Framework 4.0** with **.Net Framework 4.5**.

The following content will describe more details of how to find the workaround.

Once upon a time I have tracked the whole life cycle of these strange threads. We all know there is a [Gate Thread (thread help to monitor status of completion port threads and worker threads, only one)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2005/07/05/435726.aspx) in CLR. When my application began to go wrong, the Gate Thread would call `clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateWorkerThread` periodicity which would create a new clr thread object and a new os thread object.

```
0:004> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
04c8f6f8 6f3ea8ff KERNEL32!CreateThreadStub
04c8f744 6f3ea77b clr!Thread::CreateNewOSThread+0xba
04c8f78c 6f3eabc1 clr!Thread::CreateNewThread+0xa9
04c8f81c 6f4a6aed clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateUnimpersonatedThread+0xbb
04c8f83c 6f4a560e clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateWorkerThread+0x19
04c8f864 6f4a4457 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::EnsureEnoughWorkersWorking+0x116
04c8f94c 75973c45 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::GateThreadStart+0x431
04c8f958 771a37f5 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
04c8f998 771a37c8 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
04c8f9b0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

The new thread looked like this

```
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
XXXX   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

I have guessed this thread maybe never be resumed. It turned out I was wrong. After a while this thread had called `ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk` and `ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart` respectively.

```
0:065> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
1d54f7c0 75973c45 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
1d54f7cc 771a37f5 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
1d54f80c 771a37c8 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
1d54f824 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
  65   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

After checking the parameters of `clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc`, I found this thread would call `clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart`.

Then the magic happened.

After `clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart` ended, normally `clr!ThreadStore::RemoveThread` should be called by the **Finalizer Thread** before the thread was dead. **But this time it did not.**

No `clr!ThreadStore::RemoveThread`, just

```
0:065> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
1889fb04 7716f73a ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x14
1889fba8 7716f63b ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+0xe6
1889fbb8 75973c4c ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+0x2a
1889fbc4 771a37f5 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x15
1889fc04 771a37c8 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
1889fc1c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

So the corresponding os thread had been destroyed, but the clr thread also existed.

```
                                                                         Lock  
      ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt
XXXX   3  cb8 0043afd8      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 003f3248 0     Ukn
```

Maybe you will ask why the thread' state didn't be changed. For some reason I hadn't tracked deeper into `clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart` at that time. So I couldn't give you the answer, but I also have read the [SSCLI 2.0 source code](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917) again and have some guess again (^_^).

The `clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart` will call 'clr!SetupThreadPoolThreadNoThrow'. The following is the code snippet of 'clr!SetupThreadPoolThreadNoThrow'.

```
EX_TRY
{
    pThread = SetupThreadPoolThread(typeTPThread);
}
EX_CATCH
{
    if (pHR)
    {
        *pHR = GET_EXCEPTION()->GetHR();
    }
}
EX_END_CATCH(SwallowAllExceptions);
```

Please note the "**SwallowAllExceptions**". Then you can see this method would call `clr!SetupThreadPoolThread`. Show the code snippet again.

```
if (NULL == (pThread = GetThread()))
{
    pThread = SetupInternalThread();
}
if ((pThread != NULL) && ((pThread->m_State & Thread::TS_ThreadPoolThread) == 0))
{

    if (typeTPThread == WorkerThread)
    {
        FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ThreadPoolThread | Thread::TS_TPWorkerThread);
    }
    else if (typeTPThread == CompletionPortThread)
    {
        FastInterlockOr ((ULONG *) &pThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ThreadPoolThread | Thread::TS_CompletionPortThread);
    }
    else
    {
        FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ThreadPoolThread);
    }
}
```

Then I guess if there happened an exception when calling `clr!SetupInternalThread`, the state of thread would have no chance to be changed.

So this is the first time I thought there maybe has a minor defect in .net framework that just been triggered by my application. At the same time, one of my workmate told me that he couldn't reproduce the bug. After checking his environment, I found he used the **.Net Framework 4.5**.

So far, the bug didn't occur again after upgrading the .net framework.

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug in your code (which you haven't posted!)

Comment: I know there is bug in my code, but I don't know where and need some clues. Now I have tracked the problem into winapi layer, I want to know how my code would influence the thread.

Comment: What about option c) "used to represent an live OS thread which is now dead"? What is the state on native side? What does `~` say? Does `!runaway` ever change?

Comment: I have added a comment in the main post

Comment: I have added another comment in the main post. I will refresh the post again after I find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

### SSCCE for analyzing threads

To see how .NET creates managed threads and marks then as XXX, you can run the following code. Compile the application in Debug build, start WinDbg and run the application under the debugger. At the initial breakpoint, run the following commands:

```
sxe -c ".loadby sos clr;g" ld clr.dll;.ocommand OCOMMAND;g
```

The application will then debug itself and you will see the threads changing

```
Step                .NET threads  Unstarted  Dead     Thread objects  Native threads
1 (before started)  2             0          0        1               4
2 (Thread started)  3             1 (XXX)    0        2               5
3 (Thread running)  3             0          0        3               8
4 (Thread ended)    3             0          1 (XXX)  2               7
5 (GC ran)          3             0          1 (XXX)  2               4
```

SSCCE Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ManagedThreadDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            InformDebug("Before creating thread object.");

            var t = new Thread(ThreadRun);
            InformDebug("After creating thread object and calling Start().");

            t.Start();
            InformDebug("While thread is running.");

            t.Join();
            InformDebug("After thread was running (GC potentially not run yet).");

            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            InformDebug("After thread was running (GC hopefully ran).");
        }

        private static void ThreadRun()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        private static void InformDebug(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Trace.WriteLine("OCOMMAND .echo >>> "+message+";!threads;.echo;!dumpheap -stat -type Thread;.echo;~;g");
        }
    }
}
```

Almost complete output, shortened for brevity:

```
>>> Before creating thread object.
ThreadCount:      2
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 1
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 1074 00441310     2a020 Preemptive  02796F48:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 
   2    2 1fb8 00411258     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     MTA (Finalizer) 

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
69f02e64        1           52 System.Threading.Thread

.  0  Id: b78.1074 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: b78.2194 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: b78.1fb8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: b78.1500 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen

>>> After creating thread object and calling Start().
ThreadCount:      3
UnstartedThread:  1
BackgroundThread: 1
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 1074 00441310     2a020 Preemptive  02797334:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 
   2    2 1fb8 00411258     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
XXXX    3    0 00474900      1400 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     Ukn 

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
69f02e64        2          104 System.Threading.Thread

.  0  Id: b78.1074 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: b78.2194 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: b78.1fb8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: b78.1500 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: b78.27d8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efac000 Unfrozen

>>> While thread is running.
ThreadCount:      3
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 1
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 1074 00441310     2a020 Preemptive  02797550:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 
   2    2 1fb8 00411258     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   6    3 1d04 00474900     2b020 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
69f02e64        2          104 System.Threading.Thread

.  0  Id: b78.1074 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: b78.2194 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: b78.1fb8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: b78.1500 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: b78.27d8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efac000 Unfrozen
   5  Id: b78.2478 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efa9000 Unfrozen
   6  Id: b78.1d04 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efa6000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: b78.1fdc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efa3000 Unfrozen

 >>> After thread was running (GC potentially not run yet).
ThreadCount:      3
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 1
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       1
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 1074 00441310     2a020 Preemptive  027977FC:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 
   2    2 1fb8 00411258     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
XXXX    3    0 00474900     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     Ukn 

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
69f02e64        2          104 System.Threading.Thread

.  0  Id: b78.1074 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: b78.2194 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: b78.1fb8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: b78.1500 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: b78.27d8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efac000 Unfrozen
   5  Id: b78.2478 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efa9000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: b78.1fdc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efa3000 Unfrozen

>>> After thread was running (GC hopefully ran).
ThreadCount:      3
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 1
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       1
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 1074 00441310     2a020 Preemptive  02797380:00000000 00408378 1     MTA 
   2    2 1fb8 00411258     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
XXXX    3    0 00474900     39820 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 00408378 0     Ukn 

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
69f02e64        2          104 System.Threading.Thread

.  0  Id: b78.1074 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: b78.2194 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: b78.1fb8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: b78.1500 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen
```

### Conclusion

Threads shown as XXXX can be unstarted or dead threads. You probably won't like the answer: Where those threads come from can't be told unless you show us some code. Potential candidates:

- new Thread() statements in your code
- use of Parallel.For and similar
- use of a ThreadPool
- code in third party libraries

### Debugging thread starts and exits

Run the application in WinDbg and stop whenever a thread gets started or a thread exits.

```
sxe ct;sxe et
```

Then see where this happens and check especially the code which creates the threads. If this is not specific enough, you might also try a breakpoint on .NET thread methods.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this method to check my codes. I will update this post if I make some progress.